# Execution failed for task ':app:transform' > duplicate entry: com/nineoldandroids/animation/Animator$AnimatorListener.class

Tags: android, duplicates, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am getting this error while I try to run my Android Application,

I have used Reside Menu as merge into my Application (not by Gradle dependency) and then I am trying to integrate a payment gateway but while using a payment gateway I have to import ".aar" package.
After successfully importing, when I try to run my application at that time I got this error of library "nineoldandroids". I think this error triggered because one of the my gradle plugin is also using the same library.

Please take a look of my gradle :-

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile project(':cal_library')
    compile project(':mobicomkitui')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.droidninja:filepicker:2.0.3'
    compile 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.0'
    compile 'com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.leavjenn.smoothdaterangepicker:library:0.2.0'
    compile 'com.github.skydoves:elasticviews:1.0.6'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
    compile 'com.github.johnpersano:supertoasts:1.3.4@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha9'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.weiwangcn.betterspinner:library-material:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.+@aar'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:5.0'
    compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-core:5.0'
    compile 'com.github.kayvannj:PermissionUtils:1.0.2@aar'
}
```

So what could be the problem ?

Comment: please share complete gradle in your question

Comment: add     dependencies {
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0+'
}

Comment: As I mentioned in question, I have already used nineoldandroids into Reside Menu. Do you have any other solution ?